# How to export/save a Processing (.pde) as a screensaver on OS X?

Tags: macos, processing, screensaver

I wrote a little app in Processing that does a little animation and I really want to set that as my screensaver. I've exported it as a .app, but have no clue how to make the OS launch that app instead of an "installed" screensaver. I've done some research and it seems Macs use .saver or .qtz extensions, but I'm not well-versed with these things, so anyone know how to do this? Detailed instructions would be appreciated :)

Thanks,
Kairavi

Comment: This should be in "ask different" not in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

**[AppStartSaver](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16811/appstartsaver)**

to run your exported .app as a screensaver.

Comment: Okay I've removed my malicious down arrow.